# Does $V=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}=\Bbb R^2=U_1\oplus U_2$ where $U_1=(1,0),U_2=(0,1)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Does $\mathbf{basis}\,V=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}=\Bbb R^2=U_1\oplus U_2$ where $U_1=\mathbf{span}\,(1,0),U_2=\mathbf{span}\,(0,1)$? Is this all true? I made it to try to show that $V=U_1\oplus U_2$ can happen where $\mathbf{dim}\,V=n$ and we have $n$ subspaces in direct sum.

Obviously $U_i,i=\{1,2\}$ are subspaces of $V$ here

Comment: You have that $\dim V=2$, why do you want that $\dim V=n$ ?

Comment: @idm for $n$ subspaces of $V$, so $dim V = 2$ with $2$ subspaces here

Comment: yes it works also. You can show it by induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course ! 
for $v\in V$, $$v=v_1(1,0)+v_2(0,1)\in U_1+U_2.$$

Moreover,

if $w\in U_1\cap U_2$, $$w=w_1(1,0)=w_2(0,1)\iff(w_1,-w_2)=(0,0)\iff w_1=w_2=0\iff w=(0,0)$$
what conclude the proof.

Comment: I was mostly worried about my terminology when I constructed this.

Is $\mathbf{basis}\,V=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}=\Bbb R^2=U_1\oplus U_2$ where $U_1=\mathbf{span}\,(1,0),U_2=\mathbf{span}\,(0,1)$ a true statement, or have I demented anything?

Comment: What do you think I proved ?

Comment: It looks like you have taken the span like I have, and let it be an element of the sum of the spaces, hence proving my statement in the most part, other than mine being a direct sum rather than a sum in the first line.

Wait I see, very clever!

$V=U\oplus W$ iff $V=U+W$ and $U \cap W = \{0\}$